# Disable animation when CollectionView is touched?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uicollectionview

i have a collectionview that performs an animation when scrolling. However, while this animation is going on I cannot touch the screen to stop the scrolling. I have to wait for the scrolling to come to a complete halt.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cellsAcross: CGFloat = 1
    let spaceBetweenCells: CGFloat = 1
    let dim = (collectionView.bounds.width - (cellsAcross - 1) * spaceBetweenCells) / cellsAcross
    let finalCellFrame = cell.frame
    //check the scrolling direction to verify from which side of the screen the cell should come.
    let translation = collectionView.panGestureRecognizer.translation(in: collectionView.superview!)
    if translation.x > 0 {
        cell.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(4), y: CGFloat(finalCellFrame.origin.y), width: CGFloat(dim), height: CGFloat(44))
    } else {
        cell.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(4), y: CGFloat(finalCellFrame.origin.y), width: CGFloat(dim), height: CGFloat(44))
    }
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, delay: 0.4, animations: {(_: Void) -> Void in
        cell.frame = finalCellFrame
    })

}
```

When I remove the animation I am free to interrupt the scrolling anytime my finger touches the screen. How can I interrupt the scrolling while keeping the animation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your animation block from

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, delay: 0.4, animations: {(_: Void) -> Void in
        cell.frame = finalCellFrame
})
```

to

```
  UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, delay: 0.4, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: { 

        cell.frame = finalCellFrame

        }, completion: nil)
  })
```

Adding the `.allowUserInteraction` as an option should fix the problem.

Comment: Oh wow! Such a simple solution! That did the trick thank you!